# TextView with inputType is still getting touchlistener when its pressed although its disabled

Tags: android, android-layout

Im trying to display password using textView , I used inputType"textPassword" and its displaying doted password text which is what I want . This textView is inside relative layout I'm trying to get clicklistener from the relative layout but when I'm pressing above the textView its not clicking , when I remove the inputType it works fine. Here is what i tried till now .
`

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_changePassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/settings_password_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="@string/settings_change_password"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_settings_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/settings_password_title"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:text="123abc[enter image description here][1]"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        </RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: What do you mean by **when I'm pressing above the textView** ?

Comment: hey i meant if the press area is above the dotted area which is the text view

Comment: you are using `android:layout_width="match_parent"` for your `TextView` so it would cover almost the whole `RelativeLayout` and then its disabled and not focusable so there is some serious code issues here my man !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set Input type pro-grammatically instead of xml file

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_settings_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/settings_password_title"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="123abc[enter image description here][1]"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Then set Input type in activity

```
 TextViewPassword.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD );
 tv.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: I've edited the answer and it's working (tested). Try this out ;)

Comment: WC, my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the input type from java code instead of xml? Does that make a difference?

Comment: @jawadturk Your question isn't really clear, but as far as I've understood you're experiencing problem with the edit text when inputType is provided. Try replacing that edit text with custom edit text library for password, something like this:
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3048

Comment: its textView not editText , I'm trying to display password in textView but its hosted in relative layout , I'm using a click listener for the relative layout inorder to open another activity.when i press the part containing the textview the clicklistener isn't working . anw I found the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have used

`android:clickable="false"
 android:enabled="false"
 android:focusable="false"`

for your `TextView` so it won't receive any Click Events only when you click outside of this `TextView` your layout will receive input clicks

Also `inputType"textPassword"` has no impact on `View`'s click events.

Comment: yes i dont want to get the click event from the textView i actually want it from the relativeLayout . thats why i tried to disbale it hoping not to get the click event but its still not working.